# Change background image of a page in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a GUI for an ATM machine. I'm using Tkinter for this, but I'm unable to change the background of my page to an image. Here is the code i'm using:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)
        self.geometry('1920x1080')

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/beginscherm.png')
        self.bg_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.bg_image)
        self.bg_label.place(x=0, y=0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/pincode-check-scherm.png')
        bg_label = tk.Label(self, image=bg_image)
        bg_label.place(x=0, y=0)

        tk.Button(self, text="Page 2",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo)).pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/Keuzemenu-scherm.png')
        self.bg_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.bg_image)
        self.bg_label.place(x=0, y=0)

        tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()

        self.after(5000, lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

On the StartPage I'm trying to mage "beginscherm.png" my background image. When I run this code I get no background image just a grey screen with a button at the top. I already tried putting myself in front of the lines like is shown on the different pages.

Comment: Change `self._frame.pack()` to `self._frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)` inside `switch_frame()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for your awnser, this solved my problem